# How to access Object inside a record while using script with ScriptedMetricAggregationBuilder elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

```
"recordOne": {
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "recordtwo": {
      "properties": {
        "propertyone": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "propertytwo":{
          "type":"date"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "_parent": {
    "type": "parentrecord"
  }
}
```

Here i am trying to access recordtwo properties like `"doc.recordtwo.propertyone"`

i am getting this exception :

> 'Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=No
>   field found for [recordtwo] in mapping with types [recordOne]]'

Though i am able to access id. i.e.

```
"doc.id"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried below and it works.

```
"doc['recordtwo.propertyone']"
```